# Exist a busser gem for chefspec

Tags: testing, rspec, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm working on my cookbook's tests using [Test-Kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/wiki/Getting-Started) and I executed with serverspec, using busser-serverspec. But I wanna try to make some test with Chefscpec but if I use Test-Kitchen I don't know what is the structure of my test folders, I know what is the structure for bats and serverspec, all this thanks to [Seth Vargo](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/wiki/Getting-Started).

I execute the test using the rspec syntax like said  Sethvargo on this [source](http://code.sethvargo.com/chefspec/). I wanna try something more automated with Test-Kitchen.

Maybe I'm confused.

My question is : exist something like busser-chefspec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ChefSpec is unit testing, not integration testing. There is no busser-chefspec, and if there was, it wouldn't work.